# Optimize MySql With Order By, Group By And One Million Rows

Tags: mysql

TestAppData:
    instance_id INT
    product_id  SMALLINT
    installation_id INT
    data_id SMALLINT
    data_value_str varchar(255)
    data_value_num INT
    timestamp
    Index (installation_id)
    Index (installation_id, data_value_num)

TestAppInstallations:
    product_id SMALLINT
    installation_id INT
    Primary(product_id, installation_id)

```
   SELECT TestAppInstallations.installation_id, 
          TestAppData.data_value_num AS num1
     FROM TestAppData
LEFT JOIN TestAppInstallations ON TestAppInstallations.installation_id = TestAppData.installation_id
                              AND TestAppData.data_id =1
 GROUP BY TestAppInstallations.installation_id
 ORDER BY TestAppData.data_value_num DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Explain output

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 SIMPLE TestAppData ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 360000 Using temporary; Using filesort 
1 SIMPLE TestAppInstallations index NULL PRIMARY 6 NULL 20000 Using index
```

With the above tables, mysql query and explain output. The query is super slow, as in slow enough that I didn't let it finish. There are over 1 million rows.

I've tried indexes on installation_id and data_id, but that didn't help. I admit that I don't understand too clearly what kind of index I would need.

Is there anything else I can do to make this workable?

Edit: Sorry, 1,000,000 rows, not tables.

Comment: 1M tables? Yeah, that's not how MySQL is intended to operate… Also: intend your code 4 spaces to preserve formatting and display it as a code block.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What are you trying to get? why a LEFT JOIN? & are you using GROUP BY without any aggregate functions, just to get distinct values?

Comment: LEFT JOIN because some installation_ids will appear in the installation table and not the data table. And GROUP BY because some installations will have multiple data values that I won't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reversed the JOIN order and the query went lightning fast. So instead of joining the data table to the installation table, now the reverse.

```
SELECT TestAppInstallations.installation_id, TestAppData.data_value_num AS num1
FROM TestAppInstallations
LEFT JOIN TestAppData ON TestAppInstallations.installation_id = TestAppData.installation_id
AND TestAppData.data_id =1
GROUP BY TestAppInstallations.installation_id
ORDER BY TestAppData.data_value_num DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```